# Как вывести на экран рандомные блоки

Tags: javascript, html, css

у меня есть 20 блоков на страничке, но я хочу чтобы отображались лишь 5. В каждом блоке написана его нумерация(блок 1, блок 2 и тд.), изначально все блоки скрыты. Как мне сделать так, чтобы отображались 5 рандомных блоков (из всех 20-ти).И при каждой перезагрузке страницы, блоки должны меняться. Реализовать это все нужно на js. Надеюсь на вашу помощь. (Извиняюсь за возможные орфог. ошибки).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Взять массив, заполнить числами от 0 до 19, случайно перемешать числа, использовать первые 5 как индексы блоков, вывести их.

```js
let div = document.querySelectorAll(".hidden");
let arr = new Array(div.length).fill(0).map((_, i) => i).sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5);

for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  let rand_div = div[ arr[i] ];
  rand_div.classList.remove("hidden");
  
  // Исходный порядок блоков не меняется. Для изменения добавить:
  // rand_div.parentNode.appendChild(rand_div);

  // appendChild переносит элемент в конец списка.
}
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="hidden">0</div>
<div class="hidden">1</div>
<div class="hidden">2</div>
<div class="hidden">3</div>
<div class="hidden">4</div>
<div class="hidden">5</div>
<div class="hidden">6</div>
<div class="hidden">7</div>
<div class="hidden">8</div>
<div class="hidden">9</div>
```

1. `new Array(div.length)` — Создается массив, с пустыми ячейками в количестве `div.length` (кол-во блоков),
2. `.fill(0)` — Заполняется нулями,
3. `.map((_, i) => i)` — [.map( функция )](https://developer.cdn.mozilla.net/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) возвращает новый массив, у которого каждый элемент — результат вызова функции. Второй параметр функции (`i`) — номер элемента в массиве, его и возвращает функция. Получается массив `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`
4. `.sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5);` — `Math.random()` дает случайные числа в интервале `[0, 1)`, когда отнимается -0.5, получаются числа `[-0.5, 0.5)`. А метод [.sort( функция )](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) вызывает функцию для некторых пар элементов массива и определяет их взаимное расположение в зависимости от знака возвращенного числа. Т.к. они случайные, получается рандомная сортировка.

* [() => Стрелочные функции](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions#%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8)